# Regular expression - match letters and punctuation

Tags: java, regex

```
if (!Pattern.matches("pattern",(input.getText().toString())))
```

I want to check pattern for input and my input can have ".", "/", space, and A to z like these cases:

- ...Atoz
- Atoz....
- Atoz...Atoz
- Atoz/Atoz

What should I do with my "pattern"?

Comment: Please make sure you don't ask questions that have already been answered. There's tons of duplicates/related questions for this one. Also, it's not Android related at all.

Answer (score 4):

in your last example there is a slash (/) , what's it's implication?

otherwise: [A-Za-z.]+ should to it , it will work if there is only A-z and . (dot) characters .

Comment: As far as I understand their rudimentary question they want `[A-Za-z./]+`. Note that `[A-z]` includes way more than just letters.

Comment: @Joey : exact , didn't know that , thanks for the hint.

Comment: @user655443 : juste add it inside the bracket (after the dot) if it's juste space , if you want all whitespace characters (that include newline) put \s (minus s is important) instead of " ". i suggest you to read some tutorial on regexp , you seem quite unfamiliar with it and it's not so complex to understand.

Comment: [A-Z./-\s]+ I try this but it error it told that Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )

Comment: @user655443 : this is because java doesn't understand \s , you need to write \\s .

Comment: check your logcat , but i don't think that should be discussed here.